# FlatList item always get last item

Tags: javascript, react-native

My FlatList have a:

```
renderItem={({item, index}) => this.showItem(item, index)}
```

now my showItem return:

```
showItem = (item,index) => {
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>{index}</Text>
      <Button onPress={this.showModal(index)}></Button>
    </View>
  )}
```

now i render always 5 modal with index "4" at the top of the stack BUT index text in every item list is correct,

how to show 1 modal with correct index ?

Comment: `onPress={() => this.showModal(index)}`

Comment: `this.showModal(index)` should be `this.showModal.bind(this, index)`

Comment: @ChrisG: With latest linter settings, it will fail as they now discourage use of arrow functions inside jsx syntax

Comment: @AdityaParab Right, I don't use that syntax myself, but it's a quick fix for now

Comment: @helloReact The problem is that since `this.showModal` most likely returns nothing i.e. `undefined`, you're essentially a) calling `this.showModal(index)` right away b) using `onPress={undefined}`